# ZSH arguments after file name

Tags: command-line-arguments, zsh

I switched from bash to zsh and I was wondering if there was a way to put arguments after file name like in bash
Example:
  cp dir1 dir2 -r

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This depends only on the command, not on the shell. The shell passes the arguments in the order they're given, and makes no special treatment for arguments beginning with a `-`.

Answer (score 0):

`zsh` has some expanded/different features in the area of globbing and tab completion (two of the primary reasons folks may switch to zsh).  Both of these provide you interesting way to add command line parameters.  Is that what you are asking about?

Note also that most commands are not impacted by the shell you choose: `ls`, `awk`, `grep`, `vim`, etc.  Obviously things like `alias` and `function` that are shell commands are potentially different.

Comment: On Debian, with zsh rm dir -rf works and on MacOs it doesen't. Is there a way to fix it ? 
I have zsh 4.3.15 on macOs and 4.3.10 on Debian both using same configuration files (oh-my-zsh)